# How are the Daniel Craig Bond movie plots related?

Tags: james-bond, skyfall, chronology, casino-royale, spectre

It seems like with the older Bond films, they were more standalone "adventures" and could each be enjoyed without seeing the others. With the new movies, they definitely aren't as easy for me to follow since they are clearly more connected.

I basically started to lose it somewhere mid-Quantum. Of course I've read plot summaries of each, but the ones I've seen try to explain only what is going on in that particular movie. I've seen through Spectre, but I could easily tell I was missing a ton of main plot points.

So, my main question: How are the events throughout the Daniel Craig Bond films related as we go from Casino Royale through Spectre? I'm not looking for plot summaries of each movie, but a more overall explanation of what's actually going on, and how it connects each film to the next.

Comment: Connecting the Craig films was a weak attempt. It is quite forced and unfortunately  you aren't going to find a clean line connecting a bunch of dots to form a clear picture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In *Spectre*, all links are connected to previous *Bond* stories. Here are the links as per my understanding:

1. Spectre: Bond and  Franz Oberhauser are brothers. After the younger Bond was orphaned, Oberhauser's father, Hannes, became his temporary guardian. Believing that Bond supplanted his role as son, Oberhauser killed his father and staged his own death. He then created Spectre which is the root of all evil organizations. He told Bond that he had killed the ladies who entered into Bond's life whenever Bond has interfered with his mission.
2. Casino Royale: Le Chiffre is a mob banker who invests and transfers terrorist money. There is no proof but he was somewhere connected to Spectre. So on his failure, as of its revenge, Vesper was killed by Franz Oberhauser. Bond thinks that its the work of a man named Mr. White and he caught him at the end of this movie.
3. Quantum of Solace: Through Mr. White Bond finds Vesper Lynd's former lover, Yusef Kabira, a member of Quantum who seduces women with valuable connections. Bond spares Kabira's life and allows MI6 to arrest him.
4. Skyfall: Raoul Silva. A former MI6 officer who had previously worked under M, Silva has turned to cyberterrorism, kills M, as she left him to die after being captured years earlier.
5. Spectre: Before her death, M sends Bond a mail which leads bond to Franz Oberhauser. They have crossed each others' paths many times but at last they were in front of each other and in the end Bond defeats Franz Oberhauser.

Comment: I'd say that's pretty accurate to what they implied... though the connections were unbelievable in the first place.

Comment: It could be a little more accurate, though, especially in regard to the first two films and the Quantum organization. Le Chiffre and Mr. White (as well as Dominic Greene from *Quantum of Solace*) weren't working for Spectre directly, but for Quantum (and for that there is very well proof), which in turn was revealed to be an underorganization of Spectre in the last film. It might also be worth mentioning that Bond meets Mr. White again in *Spectre* and then continues his adventure with Mr. White's daughter.